# Я не понимаю, как вызвать класс Pas()(его интерфейс)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Код из файла py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Container(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class Pas(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class TestoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TestoApp()
    app.run()
```

Код из файла kv:

```
<Container>:
name: "first"
abc: abc
name_input: name_input
class_input: class_input
BoxLayout:
    id: abc
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.3
    spacing: 7
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: 'Введите ваши данные'
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 4
        Label:
            text: 'Фамилия и имя'
        Label:
            text:'Класс'
    BoxLayout:
        spacing:4
        TextInput:
            id: name_input
            font_size:'20sp'
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: class_input
            font_size: '20sp'
            multiline:False
    Button:
        text: 'Далее'
        on_press: Pas()
<Pas>:
    a: a
    b: b
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        id:b
        TextInput:
            id: a
            font_size: '20sp'
            multiline: False
```

Текст ошибки: NameError: name 'Pas' is not defined

Comment: Напишите так: `return Container(), Pas()`

Comment: Выводится новая ошибка: Exception: Invalid instance in App.root

Comment: А когда вызывается данная ошибка?

Comment: При запуске сразу же

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `on_press: Pas()`, а ещё у вас в контейнере сдвиг содержимого отсутствует

Comment: Сделал, всё равно почему-то не работает, выдаётся всё та же ошибка

Comment: А если, допустим, вызвать `Pas`?

Comment: Я так понял вы имеете в виду    class TestoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Pas() в таком случае открывается окно с полем ввода